# How to name $x$ when $g(f(x)) = x$?

Tags: functions

Consider two sets $A$ and $B$, and two functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow A$.

Assuming that $g$ is not the inverse of $f$, how should I call elements $a$ of $A$ such that $g(f(a)) = a$?

It's not exactly a fixed point, and a quick google search for "bi-fixed point" didn't return anything useful.

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ form a Galois correspondence, then $g \circ f$ will either be a closure operator or an interior operator, depending your conventions. Hence the fixed points of $g \circ f$ could reasonably be called "closed elements" or "open elements" in this case.

Comment: "fixed points of $g\circ f$"?

Comment: @ClementC. Turn your comment into an answer? I realize how simple it is now, but I was puzzled indeed.

Comment: @Abdallah: sure (just did it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reproduce the comment above: the best and simplest term I can think of is *fixed point of $g\circ f$.*